# F# LINQ type class fit in one

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, f#

I am learning LINQ with F# 3.0. I want to know how to convert my old class to use new LINQ features in F# 3.0
For example, I have created a simple data table in SQL Server 2008 R2, the database name is myDatabase.

```
-- Create the Table1 table.
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1] (
    [Id]        INT        NOT NULL,
    [TestData1] INT        NOT NULL,
    [TestData2] FLOAT (53) NOT NULL,
    [Name]      NTEXT      NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
USE MyDatabase

INSERT INTO Table1 (Id, TestData1, TestData2, Name)
VALUES(1, 10, 5.5, 'Testing1');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Id, TestData1, TestData2, Name)
VALUES(2, 20, -1.2, 'Testing2');
```

For F# 2.0, I can create a small class to retrieve data from Table1 and return to main program.

```
#light
module myData
open System
open System.Collections.Generic 
open System.Data
open System.Data.SqlClient

type getData(tableName: string) = class
    let sqlConn = "server=(local); Integrated Security=True; Database=MyDatabase"
    let connDB = new SqlConnection(sqlConn)

    let sqlByFun (cmdText,  unwrapping) =
        use cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connDB)
        let reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        seq { while reader.Read() do
              yield unwrapping(reader) }

    let dbTable1(tableName: string) =
        let sql = "SELECT Id, TestData1, TestData2, Name FROM Table1 ORDER BY Id"
        connDB.Open()
        let data = sqlByFun(sqlChanges, (fun reader -> 
                           (reader.GetInt32(0),  reader.GetInt32(1), 
                           reader.GetDecimal(2),reader.GetString(3)))) 
                 |> Seq.toArray
        connDB.Close()
        data 

    member this.getTable(table1) = dbTable1(table1)
```

Then in my main program: program.fs, I can use the class of myData:

```
#light
open myData
open System
open System.Collections.Generic 
open System.Data
open System.Data.SqlClient

let db = new myData.getData("Table1")
let table1Data = db.getTable("Table1")
printfn "Done"
```

Now, with F# 3.0 and LINQ, I can re-write the class like this:

```
#light
open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.SqlClient
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq

[<Generate>]
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True">
let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
let dbTable1(tableName: string) =
    let data =
        query {
              for row in db.Table1 do
              sortBy row.Id
              select (row.Id, row.TestData1, row.TestData2, row.Name)
              }
    data
```

I can see this part, the code is much shorter and cleaner, but I want this to be in a class and can be called from my main program.
How can I put this above LINQ code into a class and used by main program?
Thanks,
John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not entirely clear from your question what you're trying to achieve. In your samples, your new class (and also the method) take a `tableName` parameter, but you're always reading data from `Table1` anyway.

Writing LINQ code that is parameterized by table name is not going to be easily possible, because different tables may have different columns and so you cannot use the same type to access them. If you have different tables with the same structure, then you can probably merge them into a single table and add an additional column to distinguish between the records. If you want to access different tables, then you'll need to write different query for every table.

Regarding encapsulation in a class, you can do that easily in F# 3.0:

```
// Global declarations for SQL type provider
[<Literal>]
let connStr = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
[<Generate>] 
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<connStr> 

// Declaration of a class that exposes data access functionality
type DataAccess() =
  // Note: You can pass different connection string to 'GetDataContext'
  // if you want to keep connection string in config file instead of in code.
  let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext() 

  /// Reads data from Table1
  member x.LoadTable1() =
    query { for row in db.Table1 do 
            sortBy row.Id 
            select (row.Id, row.TestData1, row.TestData2, row.Name) }
```

Comment: Hi, Tomas:
Thank you very much.  I have to query about 10 data tables, table1 is only one simple table to use for my example.  Since I have so many data tables to query, so I put all database query into one class, then call it from main program.  But after using LINQ, I don't know how to still put all database queries into one class, therefore I ask.

Comment: what if I want the connection string to be a parameter of the DataAccess class?